# Склоняется ли название села Столбище и города Лаишево

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Прошу ответить, склоняются ли названия населенных пунктов: Столбище, Лаишево. Если можно, подтвердить правилами русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос о склоняемости названия  ***Столбище*** был уже рассмотрен.

**Лаишево** (тат. Лаеш) — город (с 9 сентября 2004 г.) в Республике Татарстан России. Административный центр Лаишевского района, образует городское поселение город Лаишево.

Согласно правилам Розенталя, название на -ево относится **к исключениям**. В этом случае допускаются оба варианта **при наличии родового слова:** из города Лаишево/Лаишева.

Но реально **варианты** существуют и при отсутствии родового слова: из  Лаишево/Лаишева.

Вот цитата из «Грамматического словаря русского языка» А. А. Зализняка: «...Очень часто встречается – как в устной речи, так и в печати – употребление данного слова [топонима на -ово, -ино] как неизменяемого, например: живет в Кунцево, подъезжаем к Останкино, в километре от Бородино вместо литературных живет в Кунцеве, подъезжаем к Останкину, в километре от Бородина. Степень распространения этого явления так значительна, что, по-видимому, **оно уже приближается к статусу допустимого варианта».**

http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy